Whatever happened to the rollout of the 'new' editor?
I honestly got reminded of this by this post and I've been interchangeably using different editors on the network. I'd love to know what the status of the stacks editor is, and what future plans on it are.
The plan had been to depreciate the 'classic' old editor for a new one. I recall there were good reasons, and practically, there's some aspects to the new editor that are handy for people used to 'classic' forums and not thinking in markdown.
Currently there's 3 different editors across the SE/SO ecosystem, the 'old' editor we're used to, the stacks editor as is used on answers here, and the slightly different (and inferior) single pane only teams editor.
I like the new editor - it was painless enough of a switch I didn't notice I got switched out but I appreciate the option to switch between markdown only and rich text mods, or the classic 2 pane mode.
In the interests of avoiding duplication of work, and easier maintenance - and (hoping this didn't get lost in the shuffle) I'm curious to the state of the newer stacks editor and what're the plans on this going forward?

Wait for the "new new editor", followed by the "new new new editor", and they'll all live happily ever after. :D

Also, unless I miss something, there's no feature request here, it's a support or discussion, I'm never sure which, but surely not a feature request when asking "what happened" to something.

Tagging has never been my strong point

The "new" Stacks editor still causes a lot of issues on SO, has a lot of bugs (e.g., I still routinely loose all of text in a post I edit with that editor), and is missing features that are routinely used on SO. We don't want it. SO would be better off if it wasn't used where it's been forced upon us.

Well, practically - I'd say on going development would include bugfixen and feature additions that our biggest site needs  – but its kinda wierd it just went quiet for a long while in general

The Stacks Editor is open-sourced, and the last release commit was on Apr 24, 2024.

This is still the editor we can opt to use through our account settings ("Enable new editor [Beta]") , right?

@Joachim yes, the same one.
